# Send Bad Data file as mail attachment only if it have records --SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

We have an `SSIS package`. It it have a 2 `script tasks` and a `data-flow task`. If any of these tasks fails the users get an `email` (through `send mail` task) . We have recently made change to `data-flow` task. If the package fails due to any bad data, the bad records will redirect into a `flat file`. we hold this `flat file` in a `variable` and send as `mail attachment`. Now, the challenge is we need to attach the file only if it has data. if it doesn't have any data, the mail sent should not include the attachment. How to do this `SSIS`? Any help will be much appreciated.

thanks
bm

Comment: First check if your variable has some value or not through precedence constraint (two separate flows if variable contains value). Then use two email task for each flow (one with attachment and one without).

Comment: Thank you. I created another data flow and get the count of the records in a variable. Then connect to the send mail task only if the variable value is greater than 0.

Comment: You should mark this as answered.